# The correct way to configure an adminhtml module

Tags: admin, configuration

I have started to try and learn how to create a module for the admin of magento and to do this i am using Magento's PHP developers guide. In it shows two ways of starting an admin module.

The first block of code I have added, the book says is the right way and the second the wrong way. It does give an explanation, but I don't understand it as it refers to a

> callback URL for an admin action

which is something I have never heard of and then goes on to talk about partial access to the admin section

Why is this considered the right way:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <modules>
                <mdg_giftregistry before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mdg_Giftregistry_Adminhtml</mdg_giftregistry>
            </modules>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and this considered the wrong way:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <giftregistry>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mdg_Giftregistry_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontname>giftregistry</frontname>
            </args>
        </giftregistry>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually they are both right, but the first one is "more right" than the second one. (I know...I sound like a 5th grade teacher). Both of them will work. The difference between them is that if you take the first approach the admin url for your module will look like `admin/giftregistry/index`. In the second case it will look like `giftregistry/adminhtml_giftregistry/index`. As you can see, with the first one you have a consistency in the admin URLs. This comes in handy if you put Varnish in front of your website. It's easier to configure it and tell it not to cache anything that comes one `/admin/`. With the second one you will need to tell it not to cache `/admin/` and `/giftregistry/adminhtml_*`. This is the only benefit I found so far (in production), but I'm sure there are others. An other one of the top of my head is that you may want to set an IP address restriction on the admin. Again you will only restrict `/admin`.
If anyone else has any other ideas feel free to add them.

Comment: Thankyou. I will stick with the one that's more right, but you made reference to "Varnish", this is a term I keep seeing around the forums but never in a tutorial, what does it refer to?

Comment: See more details about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)